# How to find the intersection of a plus sign in opencv / emgucv?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, emgucv

I have a plus sign whose intersection coordinate im  trying to find.
When i try to find contour of the plus sign, i get a single contour. I tried to get the center of the contour but the lines are not always equal, so the center is not always the intersection.

Here is the code I tried for contour:

```
             foreach (var pair in _dottracker)
                   
                {                        
                     CvTrack b = pair.Value;                        
                  
                        Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint contour3 = new Emgu.CV.Util.VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
                        Mat heir3 = new Mat();
                        CvInvoke.FindContours(grayoutdots, contour3, heir3, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.Tree, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
                        CvInvoke.DrawContours(dotImage, contour3, -1, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1);

                     
                        int xCenter = b.BoundingBox.X + b.BoundingBox.Width / 2;                        
                        int yCenter = b.BoundingBox.Y + b.BoundingBox.Height / 2;
                               
                                CvInvoke.Rectangle(dotImage, new Rectangle(b.BoundingBox.X, b.BoundingBox.Y, b.BoundingBox.Width, b.BoundingBox.Height), new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
                                CvInvoke.Circle(dotImage, new Point(xCenter, yCenter), 0, new MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), -1);
                            
                }               
                imageBox1.Image = dotImage.Bitmap;
```

This is what the output looks like :

[image: Result]

the green point is not at the center.

How do I find the intersection coordinate instead of the contour center ?

Comment: I would consider using the [Hough transform](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.1.0/document/html/4630f25d-f238-f59a-a4e7-8c8aa3b6fa0c.htm) to find straight lines, group and average horizontal/vertical lines, and intersect the lines.

Comment: @JonasH I tried houghlines but for some reason it gives me 18 set of coordinates for 2 intersecting lines(a plus sign), i tried contour because of houghlines result.

Comment: Did you try plotting the lines? Or adjusting the threshold and other parameters? I would assume that you would get at least some parallel lines that needs to be averaged.

Comment: @JonasH How do I do that? i tried putting the coords in an array and sort them but I was unable to make out which one belongs to which line.

Comment: @JonasH I drew the hough line on the  plus sign and it looks like there are only 2 lines on the image but there are 18 coordinates.